Extract specific numbers of substrings from a string python
I have many strings, Here is one example string:
test_str = "Discharge Attending:<pgno1> Bpractitionert practitioner name XX<pgno1> Discharge Diagnoses:<pgno1> X<pgno1> X<pgno2> patient name X (id #XXXXXX, dob: XX/XX/XX) gastro-esophageal reflux disease with esophagitis; atrial fibrilpractitionertion; dipractitionertation of unnamed symptom Admit Service: Med/Surg PCP: practitioner name<pgno2> "
if you see there are pagenumber tags in the string, i.e. "<pgno1> ","<pgno2> "
***( Note: The page no tags include a whitespace at the end)
I want to extract the numbers from this tags and save it in a list, also remove these tags after getting the list.
for example:
the output should have
op_list = [1,2]
op_str = "Discharge Attending:Bpractitionert practitioner name XXDischarge Diagnoses:XXpatient name X (id #XXXXXX, dob: XX/XX/34) gastro-esophageal reflux disease with esophagitis; atrial fibrilpractitionertion; dipractitionertation of esophageal stricture Admit Service: Med/Surg PCP: practitioner name"

I tried using regex and this method:
re.search('(\d+)',test_str)

But not giving the correct output. Is there any quick way to get this done, because I have around 1000's of such strings to be worked on.

I.e. re.findall(r'<pgno(\d+)>', text), and the same will work if you want to replace, you do not just need the parentheses then.
